How to Ensure Date Cells in Excel Default to "Date" Format Instead of "Custom" When Generated with Apache POI?
I am generating an Excel file using Apache POI in Java, and I am formatting some cells to display dates. However, when I open the Excel file and inspect the cells, I notice that the formatted date cells are categorized under Custom instead of Date in Excel
private void createCell(Workbook wb, Sheet sheet, Row row, int columnCount, Object value) {
Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);

if (value instanceof Date) {
    // Create a CellStyle for the custom date format
    CellStyle dateCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    
    // Set the custom date format "dd-MM-yyyy"
    dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    // Set the cell value and apply the style
    cell.setCellValue((Date) value);
    cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
} else if (value instanceof Integer) {
    cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
} else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
} else if (value instanceof String) {
    cell.setCellValue((String) value);
} else {
    cell.setCellValue(value != null ? value.toString() : "");
}

}
I need these cells to be categorized under the Date format in Excel.
What I Have Tried:

Using different date formats, such as dd-MM-yyyy or MM/dd/yy.

Disabling any additional styling to test the behavior with just the date value.

Setting locale-specific formats like Locale.US or Locale.UK.

Manually inspecting the generated file's regional settings in Excel.


My Goal:
I want the cells to:

Be categorized under Date format instead of Custom in Excel.

Is there a way to ensure that the cells default to the Date format category in Excel? If not, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Have you tried not setting a format?

@M.Deinum yes it is setting to general format

Well according to the javadoc there is not DATE type in Excel and Excel will only detect it through one of the default date/time formats. So you would need to use one of those try d/m/YY as that appears to be a default one. See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
